# Merge function doesn't work as expected in R

Tags: r, merge

I created two test datasets:

mymerge1

```
col1 col2
x    29
y    23
z    66
```

mymerge2

```
col1 col2
x    black
y    red
```

This command: `mymerge3<-merge(mymerge1, mymerge2, by="col1", all.mymerge1=TRUE)`
gives me this:

```
col1 col2.x col2.y
x    29     black
y    23     red
```

But where is the third row `z` of `mymerge1`? Why does't `all.mymerge1=TRUE` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `mymerge3<-merge(mymerge1, mymerge2, by="col1", all.x=TRUE)`, the name of the `all.x` parameters is not changed.

Comment: Ohhhh okayyyyy....had no idea that the x in all.x doesn't change. Thank you very much. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dplyr** method:

```
mymerge3 <- dplyr::inner_join(mymerge1, mymerge2, by = "col1")
```

**inner_join** keeps all the rown from both datasets

Comment: This is incorrect. It works after even if the results have NA after I corrected my code based on the first answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok my bad, i'll edit this to avoid confusion